# How do you properly install SVM-Light on python?

Tags: python, windows, setup.py, svmlight

I am at my windows machine and I am trying to install the extension SVM-Light https://pypi.org/project/svmlight/ to my Python directory. I have already extracted the files to my directory folder but I cannot seem to be able to install it properly.

With the command `pip install svmlight` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

with the command `python setup.py install` on the prompt, I get a very similar error, but on the prompt

the documentation states:

```
Installation
------------
PySVMLight uses distutils for setup. Installation is as simple as

$ chmod +x setup.py

$ ./setup.py --help

$ ./setup.py build

If you want to install SVMLight to your PYTHONPATH, type:

$ ./setup.py install
```

but typing in these commands also returns a syntax error.

If anyone has ever installed this package on python-windows, and knows how to comprehensively explain how to do so, and could help me on this matter, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: on  https://pypi.org/project/svmlight/ it shows it was released in 2012 - it seems they forget this module and it may have mistakes. You may have to dig in code to find mistake and correct code.

Comment: strange is I can install it on LInux without problems using `pip install svmlight`. Tested with Linux Mint 19.3 and Python3.7 and Python 2.7

Comment: It installs without problem but it doesn't work - probably I have to install also C/C++ version from http://svmlight.joachims.org/  .

Comment: moduie works without problems in `Python 2.7` - probably it is so old that it was created when Python 2.7 was main version. It would need changes in C/C++ wrapper to work with `Python 3.x`. It can't create for Python 3.7 even when I use `setup.py`